# Hide the sidenav by clicking outside the menu in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a project in `Angular material` where from the home.component by clicking on the 'menu' icon I show the menu.component that contains the sidenav.

What I want to achieve is to close the sidenav by clicking outside the menu (anywhere), currently it only closes by clicking on the icon.

This is my home.component.html:

```
<div>
  <app-header (SideNavToggle)="sidenav.toggle()"></app-header>
</div>

<mat-sidenav-container>

  <mat-sidenav #sidenav id="sidebar-panel" fixedInViewport="true">
    <app-menu (closeSideNav)="sidenav.close()"></app-menu>
  </mat-sidenav>

</mat-sidenav-container>
```

This is my home.component.ts:

```
export class HomeComponent {

  @Output() SideNavToggle = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
  ) { }

  public goHome() {
    this.router.navigateByUrl("/");
  }

  public openSidenav() {
    this.SideNavToggle.emit();
  }
}
```

This is my menu.component.html

```
<mat-nav-list class="sidenav-list">
  <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="nav.route" *ngFor="let nav of fillerNav" (click)="onToggleClose()" fxLayoutAlign="space-around center">
    <mat-icon class="iconMenu">{{nav.icon}}</mat-icon>
    <span>{{nav.name}}</span>
  </a>
</mat-nav-list>
```

This is my menu.component.ts:

```
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() closeSideNav = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public fillerNav = [
    {name: "Company", route: "/companies", icon: "local_shipping"},
    {name: "Client", route: "/clients", icon: "people"},
    {name: "Employee", route: "/employees", icon: "account_circle"},
    {name: "Product", route: "/products", icon: "shop"},
    {name: "Store", route: "/store", icon: "store"},
    {name: "Invoice", route: "/invoices", icon: "description"},
    {name: "Orders", route: "/orders", icon: "add_shopping_cart"}
  ]

  public onToggleClose() {
    this.closeSideNav.emit();
  }

}
```

All the information I find is using JQuery or from AngularJS, I need to know if there is any property of angular material to achieve this or if I need to change something in my current project:

Answer (score 3):

If you want, you can also use the `hasBackdrop` property to achieve this behavior. Simply place this property on the `mat-sidenav-container` tag and it should be working.

```html
<mat-sidenav-container [hasBackdrop]="true">...</mat-sidenav-container>
```

You can read about this property in the Angular Material documentation here: [link to the docs](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/api)

I have also prepared a working demo which you can check it out: [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m8w1fy-cafctb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsidenav-autosize-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

Bind your mat-nav-list into the component:

```
<mat-nav-list #sideNav class="sidenav-list">

export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('sideNav ') sideNav :ElementRef
```

Then listen with @HostListener:

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  documentClick(event: any): void {
    if (event.currentTarget.activeElement !== this.sideNav?.nativeElement) {
      this.onToggleClose();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in app.component.html to close sidenav when click event is happening outside sidenav:

```
  <mat-sidenav-content (click)="handleClose()">
```

and during the opening of the sidenav take the instance in handleOpenSideNav

```
  handleOpenSideNav(sidenav: any) {
    sidenav.open();
    this.sidenav = sidenav;
  }
  handleClose() {
    if (this.sidenav && this.sidenav.opened) {
      this.sidenav.close();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add   `(click)="sidenav.toggle()"` in your `mat-sidenav` tags. It's all

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).